# Fast calculation of statistic on large amount of documents in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, optimization, mongoose, nosql

My document schema:

```
  {
    symbol: String,
    exchange: String,
    price: Number,
    amount: Number,
    type: {
        type: String,
        enum: ['buy', 'sell']
    },
    timestamp: Number
}, {
    autoIndex: false,
    id: false,
    versionKey: false
});
```

There are 40+ millions documents in my MongoDb Atlas cluster. All docs are appending to one large collection.

I need to calculate some values in filtered collection  by at least one  param - *symbol*. *Timestamp*, *price* and *amount* minimal and maximum ranges are optional. After collection filterring i must calculate 
count of documents depends on type, sum of amounts depends on type, min/max/average of price and amount. Furthermore, depends on timestamps of firts and last documents in filtered collection, there is should be created line chart data relative to timestamp ranges.

I`m using Mongoose ORM on Node.js, and find() method working very slow with handling ~100K docs for 100s!

How to achieve maximum performance for my case?

Comment: After collection filterring i must calculate count of documents depends on type, sum of amounts depends on type, min/max/average of price and amount - Are you trying to do groupby here? Or it will be a query with {type: "sometype"}?. Can you post sample queries?

Comment: Firstly, i had trying something like that: 
let cursor =  Trade.find(findFilters).lean(true).cursor()
      let trades = [];

      cursor.on('data', (item) => {
          trades.push(item)
      })

      cursor.on('close', () => {
        res.send({
            symbol: req.query.symbol,
            type: req.query.type,
            params: req.body,
            result: calculate(trades)
        })
      });

where findFilters - { exchange: 'exchange', symbol: 'symbol', type: 'sell' ... }

Comment: A codeblock is worth a 1000 words. I highly suggest you add code examples to the question (not as a comment!) so we understand what you are trying to achieve and where it fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating of index { symbol: "hashed", price: 1, timestamp: 1 } reduced the response time to an adequate 1 second.